# Rust: Why Pin must hold a pointer?

Tags: rust

I've thorougly read Pin's documentation and few articles about it. I have no questions about Pin and why does it matter. Except one: Why Pin must hold a pointer? Why it is unable to keep data directly (e.g. own it)?

Maybe, such decision was made because Pin exists only at compile time?

Comment: It could work, it would be just harder to ensure soundness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every type in Rust is trivially movable, so if you have a value of that type in a variable and there are no active borrows, you can always move it into a different location.

The whole point of `Pin` is that the data it refers to is "pinned" to a specific location, making that value unmovable (unless the pinned type implements `Unpin`). However, `Pin` itself is a movable type, just like any other type, so as long as it's not borrowed you can move it around freely.

What happens if `Pin` directly contains the pinned data instead of using a reference? Then moving the `Pin` around would also move around all of its fields, including the pinned data it contains, which would obviously break the pinning guarantees of the type.

Because of this, `Pin` can't contain the pinned data correctly, and it can only work with pointer types that don't move around the data being pointed to, especially when the pointers themselves are moved (which includes standard pointer types like `&T`, `&mut T`, `Box<T>`, `Rc<T>`, etc.).

Comment: While this looks like it correct answer, it isn't because just like the contract of `Pin::new_unchecked()` is that the value referenced won't be moved, the contract of `PinOwned::new_unchecked()` could be that the `Pin` won't be moved.

Comment: Thanks . That is the clearest explanation I've heard!

Comment: @Jujumba Except it isn't correct, as I've explained.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sure that's technically correct, but I think such a hypothetical type would be completely useless since every piece of code that even touched a `PinOwned` would make sure to not move it or risk UB, which removes the whole point of having a safe API to deal with pinned values anyways. In the context of what `Pin` _actually_ is, i.e. a safe API for pinned values, I think my answer is suitable.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand your point. `Pin::new_unchecked()` doesn't move the value, right? But `Pin::new()` does?

Comment: And currently every piece of code touching the _value_ needs to make sure not to move it. I agree it would make reasoning about unsafe harder, but calling it "completely useless" is just not true.

Comment: @Jujumba Currently, neither `Pin::new()` nor `Pin::new_unchecked()` move the value. If your idea would be true, both would move it.